# Json.net deserialization error (JSONReaderException)

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Code in the main program

```
controller.modelToFile("passwords/test.json");
controller.deJSONizeModel("passwords/test.json");
```

Controller's modelToFile:

```
    public void modelToFile(String filename) {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, JSONizeModel());
    }
```

Controller's JSONizeModel:

```
    public String JSONizeModel() {
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings jss = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
        jss.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver dcr = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
        dcr.DefaultMembersSearchFlags |= System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        jss.ContractResolver = dcr;
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, jss);
    }
```

Controller's deJSonizeModel:

```
    public void deJSONizeModel(String json) {
        model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
    }
```

Model:

```
class Model : IModel    {
    private IList<Password> passwords = new List<Password>();

<...>
```

File test.json:

```
{
  "passwords": [
    {
      "description": "example password 1",
      "password": "p1"
    },
    {
      "description": "example password 2",
      "password": "p2"
    },
    {
      "description": "This is the password",
      "password": "the password"
    }
  ]
}
```

Password class:

```
    public String description { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }

    public Password(String description, String password)  {
        this.description = description;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Please help. The exception is Newtonsoft.Json.JSONReaderException.

Program log:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Additional information: Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

Comment: Could you add more information about the exception to the post? InnerException if any, stacktrace perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it! The argument to `deJSONizeModel` is a FILE but JSON is required!

Comment: Yes, it was your answer, but you posted it in the question section. I extracted it and posted it here on your behalf.